# Using R for webscraping: HTTP error 503 despite using long pauses in program

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to search the [ProQuest Archiver](http://www.pqarchiver.com/titles.html) using R. I'm interested in finding the number of articles for a newspaper containing a certain keyword.

It generally works well using the `rvest` tool. However, the program sometimes breaks down. See this minimal example:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

# Retrieve the title of the first search hit on the page of search results
for (p in seq(0, 150, 10)) {
  searchURL <- paste("http://pqasb.pqarchiver.com/djreprints/results.html?st=advanced&QryTxt=bankruptcy&sortby=CHRON&datetype=6&frommonth=01&fromday=01&fromyear=1908&tomonth=12&today=31&toyear=1908&By=&Title=&at_hist=article&at_hist=editorial_article&at_hist=front_page&type=historic&start=", p, sep="")
  htmlWeb <- read_html(searchURL)
  nodeWeb <- html_node(htmlWeb, ".text tr:nth-child(1) .result_title a") 
  textWeb <- html_text(nodeWeb)
  print(textWeb)
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

This works for me sometimes. But if I run this or similar scripts a couple of times, it breaks down at the same point and I get an error on the 12th iteration (`p=120`):

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503.
```

I tried circumventing this by putting in pauses of escalating lengths, but that doesn't help.

I've also considered:

- saving which result pages cannot be reached and writing separate scripts for those cases
- changing my IP some time through the program?
- quit and start R some time through the program?

I thank you for any comments.

Comment: I encountered the same problem a few days back and then came to know that sometimes the host decline the botic actions on their pages though i couldn't came across any solution for that .

Comment: I know [this](http://www.policyuncertainty.com/media/BakerBloomDavis.pdf) paper uses this archive in a large scale way, so in general it should be possible ...

Comment: It's possible that since the paper came out and people started hammering their site, that they put limits on it. Save your data so you aren't running the same query over and over and run this over the course of several days, or across several machines. This is not a limitation of R

Comment: @cory Yes, that might be right, although I don't hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we use a combination of:

1. random pauses,
2. randomly changing the user agent (as suggested by [hrmrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119447/using-r-for-webscraping-http-error-503-despite-using-long-pauses-in-program#comment63685626_38124071)'s comment) and
3. trying multiple times when a URL access returns an error.

It still happens that we cannot fully access all URLs and in that case we just save the info on where that happened and go on.

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 3):

Try being a bit more human-like in the delays. This works for me (multiple tries):

```
library(xml2)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

to_get <- seq(0, 150, 10)
pb <- progress_estimated(length(to_get))

map_chr(to_get, function(i) {
  pb$tick()$print()
  searchURL <- paste("http://pqasb.pqarchiver.com/djreprints/results.html?st=advanced&QryTxt=bankruptcy&sortby=CHRON&datetype=6&frommonth=01&fromday=01&fromyear=1908&tomonth=12&today=31&toyear=1908&By=&Title=&at_hist=article&at_hist=editorial_article&at_hist=front_page&type=historic&start=", i, sep="")
  htmlWeb <- read_html(searchURL)
  nodeWeb <- html_node(htmlWeb, "td > font.result_title > a")
  textWeb <- html_text(nodeWeb)
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
  textWeb
}) -> titles

print(trimws(titles))

##  [1] "NEWSPAPER SPECIALS."                                      
##  [2] "NEWSPAPER SPECIALS."                                      
##  [3] "New Jersey Ice Co. Insolvent."                            
##  [4] "NEWSPAPER SPECIALS."                                      
##  [5] "NEWSPAPER SPECIALS"                                       
##  [6] "AMERICAN ICE BEGINNING BUSY SEASON IN IMPROVED CONDITION."
##  [7] "NEWSPAPER SPECIALS"                                       
##  [8] "THE GERMAN REICHSBANK."                                   
##  [9] "U.S. Exploration Co. Bankrupt."                           
## [10] "CHICAGO TRACTION."                                        
## [11] "INCREASING FREIGHT RATES."                                
## [12] "A.O. BROWN & CO."                                         
## [13] "BROAD STREET GOSSIP"                                      
## [14] "Meadows, Williams & Co."                                  
## [15] "FAILURES IN OCTOBER."                                     
## [16] "Supplementary Receiver for Heinze & Co."
```

I randomized the sleep call value, simplified the CSS target a bit, added a progress bar and automagically made a vector. You prbly ultimately want a data.frame from this data, so `?purrr::map_df` for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! We tried randomizing the pauses, but that didn't do the trick. Thanks for all the other data wrangling magic. So unfortunately, I still get an error (same error message) if I try running this script twice.

Comment: hrm. I've got one other idea but won't have time to code it up. Try using `httr::GET` with a valid `user_agent()` parameter and then pass the `content()` result to `read_html()` and see if that helps. I wonder, though, if your IP already got on a "potential bot blacklist" and that you may need to wait a few hrs or a day-ish to have that trickle off (can you try it from another network or even spin up a small cloud instance?)