# Error 503 Scraping multiple url from the same web without error 503

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr, rcurl

I'm **scraping** Amazon webpage with more than 500 asins, it means more than 500 urls. I use sys.Sleep(6) between each asin to scrape, and sys.Sleep(300) when R is scraping at the asins number 100, but i get an error 503 each time at the same point, in the asin 101.

I tried to increase the time to sleep at every 100 asins scraped but it doesn't work. ¿Are there maybe any package than can help me or some instruction tu put in code to help me?

My code is this:

```
df<-NULL

r=0

for(i in asin.list$V1) {
 print(i)

 url<-paste0("https://www.amazon.es/gp/offer-listing/",i,"/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new")

 Sys.sleep(6)
 r=r+1
 dades<-read_html(url)

 url<-(url)
 asin<-(i)
 rating<-dades %>% html_nodes("div span span a i span.a-icon-alt") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
 opinions<-dades %>% html_nodes("span.a-size-small a.a-link-normal") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()

 if(length(rating)==0){ rating<-"-"}
 if(length(opinions)==0){ opinions<-"-"}

 info<-data.frame(asin=asin,rating=rating,opinions=opinions)
 df<-rbind(df,info)

 if (r %in% seq(100,1000,100) ){
 Sys.sleep(300)
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you start from number 90, does it stop at number 101?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: E.g. by changing the loop:  `for(i in asin.list$V1[90:400]) { ...}`

Comment: it stops at r = 76

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119447/using-r-for-webscraping-http-error-503-despite-using-long-pauses-in-program

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is not in R code, but rather in Amazon blocking your calls. A good practice is to randomize pauses `Sys.sleep(2 + rnorm(1))` and close connections

```
dades <- read_html(url)
closeAllConnections()
```

Also, you may try the `RSelenium` package, where you can mask your scraping intentions.

Example: https://tykiww.github.io/2018-04-05-Selenium-Scraping/