# How to prevent 503 errors when trying to access any site from RStudio Cloud?

Tags: r, rvest, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

So, After scouring the net for solutions that might work, I'm just not finding them, even though the question has been asked in tons of ways with various answers here and elsewhere.
I cannot get past this "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 503." issue.
I'm using RStudio cloud, the latest version, on a windows based laptop from my home. I've tried so many things, but simply cannot get past this initial "handshake" of my computer with virtually ANY site. I've tried Amazon, IMDB, Glassdoor etc etc, just to try and practice for text mining for my school work, and I can't go any further as they all throw this issue.

Here is the code I'm trying today:

```
#Un-comment and load in the necessary packages, if required. 

library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#Assign the pages url and read it in.
link = "https://www.glassdoor.ca/Reviews/Tesla-Reviews-E43129.htm"
page = read_html(link)

#Inspect and assign names to required associated html/css tags from the pages code.

emp_status = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".eg4psks0") %>% 
  html_text()
headline = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".reviewLink") %>% 
  html_text()
rating = page %>% 
  html_nodes("#ReviewsFeed .mr-xsm") %>% 
  html_text()
pros = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__fullWidth:nth-child(1) span") %>% 
  html_text()
cons = page %>% 
  html_nodes(".v2__EIReviewDetailsV2__fullWidth:nth-child(2) span") %>% 
  html_text()

#Save a data frame with the associated variables and their contents for analysis.

tesla_emp_reviews = data.frame(emp_status, headline, rating, pros, cons, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Please help. This is incredibly frustrating. I should be working on learning looping functions over multiple pages, "rests" (robots.txt/Polite pkg) and mapping (purr::) et al months ago, but will not go further until I can at least see this part of the process function correctly.
Thank you all...

Comment: I've run the code and not experienced any issues. Is there a particular reason you're using rstudio cloud? Try running it from your laptop instead.

Comment: StackOverflow tip: Describe the problem in the title, and also the first sentence (as that is what is included in the email summaries, for instance). Then describe what you have tried, and more detail, after that. Most people will only give your question a glance, and make a split-second decision if it is something they can help with.

Comment: RStudio Cloud is running on a server, and so the request will be going from that server? You need to contact whoever runs that server, or if this is a university account then maybe ask your tutor? If it works for everyone else in the class, maybe they've not given your user the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

500 HTTP response codes are supposed to be server side. If you can access these sites in your web browser, but can't through R/RStudio, something is presumably blocking RStudio network communication in particular.

First, I would [go into Windows Firewall settings and make certain R and RStudio are allowed to communicate over the network.](https://jackboxgames.happyfox.com/kb/article/28-how-to-whitelist-and-resolve-issues-in-antivirus-software-and-firewalls/)

Second, if that fails, [look at this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119447/using-r-for-webscraping-http-error-503-despite-using-long-pauses-in-program) It seems some sites may put restrictions on automated web scraping. They add sleep commands as a work around.